# How do I uninstall the shortcuts that come with Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

So I am running OS X El Capitan on my Macbook air. I just installed the chrome browser recently and I noticed it installed a few shortcuts onto launchpad. These shortcuts were to youtube, gmail, and google drive. When clicking on the shortcuts it opens chrome to the correct webpage. I have already gone to chrome://apps and uninstalled all of the apps but the shortcuts still do not go away. I have searched through my application folder but I cannot find the shortcuts and have tried deleting chrome. Rebooting doesn't do a thing either. I installed chrome from google's official website too. [image]

please help me!!! I do not care if I have chrome anymore I just do not want these shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still on Mavericks, but here it is in the

~/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized

You can do it in Chrome as well.

Go to: (type in chrome browser)

```
 chrome://apps/
```

and Delete it